# Azure Bot Service - Cannot access to Channel configuration, The resource you are looking for has been removed

Tags: azure, botframework, chatbot

Can't access to the channel already configured, for example I want to get the secret directline's key, but I got the message "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.", do you know if azure is getting some kind of error related to this? I'll really appreciate if you know something.

Comment: Looks like a service issue, are you able to create a support ticket in Azure?

Comment: It was a temporary error of azure, it's already working, thank you by the way.